# The range of the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, defined by $ f(x)=\frac{\sin\pi [x]}{s^{2}+5}$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $[x]$ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ for
>   any real number $x$. The range of the function $f : R → R$, defined by
>   $ f(x)=\frac{\sin\pi [x]}{s^{2}+5}$:
>
> A.$ (−1, 1)$
>
> B. $[−1, 1]$
>
> C. $\{−1, 1\} $
>
> D. $\{0\}$

The numerator oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, and the denominator can take any positive value. So the range is within $(-1,1)$ ??

I don't know how to find out if the function touches $-1$ and $1$?

Is the answer (A)$(-1,1)$ ??

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: numerator is always 0

Comment: "The numerator oscillates between $-1$ and $1$": and that's exactly where you might want to ask yourself why the authors went to such lengths to tell you what those square parenthesis where.

Comment: OH! Any integer multiplied by pie will always give a sin value of $ 0$.

Comment: My bad, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found by the questioner already: Since $[x]$ is always an integer, 
$$\sin \pi [x] = 0$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Thus the range is $\{0\}$.